# How to get extended permissions to a facebook profile using fb_graph gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, fb-graph

Using fb_graph gem

To get basic information from a facebook user :

```
fb_user = FbGraph::User.new(FB_USER_ID)
fb_user = fb_user.fetch
```

That works pretty fine.

Now I need also to access biography and location

```
fb_user.bio 
fb_user.location.name
```

Location is nil so I get an error, and bio is blank.

In Facebook API doc http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Looks like bio needs user_about_me or friends_about_me permissions.

So I thought that should mean that I need to generate an access token for my app, which I did:

```
app = FbGraph::Application.new(FB_APP_ID, :secret => FB_APP_SECRET)                         
access_token = app.get_access_token() 
fb_user = FbGraph::User.new(authentication.uid, access_token)
```

But then I get :

```
undefined method `[]' for GENERATED_TOKEN:Rack::OAuth2::AccessToken::Legacy
```

I am not quite sure how to get around that. This is my first day with the Facebook API

QUESTION: How do get extended permission for my app in order to get bio and user location?

Comment: How you did your authentication?

Comment: I am using OmniAuth gem + AuthOmni-Facebook gem

Answer (score 0):

In order to extend the permission you have to add them in the OmniAuth provider configuration

```
provider :facebook, APP_ID, APP_SECRET, {:scope => 'publish_stream,offline_access,email'}
```

Then you will have permission to post in the user timeline and etc..

You can also follow this tutorial that is a little bit old, but you can use the concepts

[Facebook Integration With Omniauth and Devise on Rails 3](http://blog.assimov.net/blog/2010/11/21/facebook-integration-with-omniauth-and-devise-on-rails-3/)

**Permissions**

The permissions Facebook provides are available in the Facebook site itself.

Check in this link [Facebook Permissions](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/#permissions)

Comment: I added user_about_me to the scope list and I still don't get biography and location info. But thanks already for the article. That's helpful

Comment: Added all these  {:scope => 'publish_stream, offline_access, email, user_about_me, user_location, user_website, user_hometown'} still they  remain 'nil'

Comment: You can check all permissions in the link I added

Comment: That's what I have been doing. I'll keep you posted but so far no success.